# Browse only images while upload in phtml form in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I want to upload image file. When I click browse button. the browser window show all files.I want only image file.I tried this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832255/show-only-image-files-in-input-type-file-browse-window

When I click browse button, the below browser window appears,

[image]

How to fix this...

Comment: it's not possible my friend

Comment: but in backend, when adding product images,it shows only image file.Please check

Comment: give me some time I will check and let you know

Comment: They have using Flash Uploader in Magneto

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the types if your block is initializing proper parent block classes:

```
$this->getConfig()->setFilters(array(
    'images' => array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Images (.gif, .jpg, .png)'),
        'files' => array('*.gif', '*.jpg', '*.png')
    ),
    'media' => array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Media (.avi, .flv, .swf)'),
        'files' => array('*.avi', '*.flv', '*.swf')
    ),
    'all'    => array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('All Files'),
        'files' => array('*.*')
    )
));
```

- http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.8/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Media/Uploader.php

Also take note Magento by default uses Flash (Adobe FLEX) for the uploading process, If this is disabled than the alternative methods would need to be considered.

Here is a snippet of the FLEX initilization JS Object. Note the loop of config filters and `addTypeFilter`:

```
    handleBridgeInit: function() {
        this.uploader = this.flex.getBridge().getUpload();
        if (this.config.filters) {
            $H(this.config.filters).each(function(pair) {
                this.uploader.addTypeFilter(pair.key, pair.value.label, pair.value.files);
            }.bind(this));
            delete(this.config.filters);
            this.uploader.setUseTypeFilter(true);
        }
```

- http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.8/js/mage/adminhtml/flexuploader.js

Further Reading:

- http://code007.wordpress.com/2012/06/08/using-magento-flex-uploader/

Comment: How it can be integrate with custom admin form?